# How can I ensure the whole paragraph is in one page in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I have a document that is consists of many smaller portions, say paragraphs. What I want is, each of the paragraphs will be in just one page. It will not be broken in two consequent pages. In that case, the whole paragraph/portion will shift to next page.

Is it possible with Microsoft Word or LATEX? This is needed to be done programmatically. Manual edit is not useful.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the **'Keep lines together'** option can do what you want. It can be applied automatically to existing documents, however I'm not aware of a way to make this a default for all new documents (i.e.Normal.dot etc).

This website has some information on how to use this option: http://www.itsupportguides.com/office-2010/word-2010-separate-paragraphs-on-new-page/

Comment: Known in the trade as widow and orphan control and Word has paragraph option for it.

Answer (score 1):

In LaTeX each paragraph could be put into a `minipage` environment

```
\begin{minipage}[position]{width}
       text
\end{minipage}
```

There is a useful [discussion on keeping units of text on the same page in the UK TUG FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=nopagebrk). The UK TUG FAQ also has a section on [automatic provision of the mandatory width parameter for a minipage](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=varwidth).

If you have more questions after that you may want to try the StackExchange TeX and friends site https://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually insert a page break after each paragraph via the Insert tab.  See [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-page-break-HA010031062.aspx#BM1) for more details.

Comment: I know that. But I want something different. I have further clarified the question.

Comment: @Gulshan You can write a macro in Word VBA that will do essentially the same thing.  I'm not sure what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word, you can do one of two things:

1. Do a Find and Replace.  Search for `^p` and replace with `^m`.  The downside of this is that if you have multiple `^p`'s between your paragraphs, you'll also get multi-page breaks.  Also, if you add paragraphs later, you will have to do the Find and Replace again.
2. The more "programmatic" way is to go to the `Format` menu, select `Paragraph...` and under the `Indents and Spacing` tab, in the `Spacing` section, set `After:` to a large number (longer than the length of the page), like 1000 pt (the maximum for MS Word 2011 for Mac is 1584 pt).  This method has the advantage that you only have to do it once.  New paragraphs will follow the same formatting.