# Keep lines together in Word; but the heading gets cut off

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-formatting

I recently found out about the '[keep lines together](https://superuser.com/q/285177/46516)' option in Word, and it has saved me vast amounts of the worst kind of proofing. What remains are odd headings here and there in lengthy documents where the subsequent paragraph was kept together, but pushed to the next page, leaving an orphan heading.

How do I get the heading to get folded into the push of the paragraph to the next page? Each heading is linked to a table of contents and has all of the attendant markup.

Also, in instances where there is a leading line saying something like,

> Please go to this link for more information:
>
> http:\\www.moreinformation.com

How do I keep these together?

Comment: What is the "push of the paragraph"?

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski "push" as in, when a split paragraph gets *pushed* as a whole to the next page; so how do you keep the leading line ("Please go...") with the following line ("http:...") or paragraph?

Comment: if the lines are separate paragraphs, than you set the property "keep with next paragraph" for the "Please go" paragraph (or something that sounds like that. It can be found in the same place as "keep lines together" option).

Comment: Another option is what Scott have proposed: to keep those two lines in the same paragraph. With the "Keep lines together" option it would do as well, but it requires that you replace the "end of paragraph" into "end of line", just as Scott has written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I get the heading to [go] to the next page [with the subsequent paragraph]?

The only thing I can suggest is to manually unset the ‘Keep lines together’ option on all paragraphs that immediately follow a heading.  (It may be possible to automate that with VBA.)

#### How do I keep these together?

A couple of possibilities.  One:

```
Please go to this link for more information:Enter
http://www.moreinformation.comEnter
```

and set the ‘Keep with next’ property on the first paragraph.

Or:

```
Please go to this link for more information:Shift+Enter
Shift+Enter

http://www.moreinformation.comEnter
```

thus creating a single paragraph that is three lines long (with the second line being blank).

Answer (score 0):

Use Styles!

And in heading-style definition be sure to check "keep with the next paragraph" checkbox. It can be found in the same place as the "keep lines together". (I use localized version of Word and I can't say the exact English name). Also be sure, that you uncheck it in the definition of the style you use for a base text.

I can't answer the latter question because I don't understand it (see comments)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually simple.
As mentioned, you need to use Styles, but here's the trick:

- you need to tell Word what style *follows* your header.

Modify your header style as so:

**Line and Page Breaks:**
(found under "Format" > "Paragraph" - lower left corner of modify style box)

1. CHECK "Keep With Next"
2. UNCHECK everything else.

**Properties**
(first section of modify style box)

1. Style for following paragraph <~  Set this to whatever style you are using for the paragraph under your header.  Most people would set this to "Normal".

If you had some other style listed in the "following" box, then Word was not seeing your paragraph as the "next thing", and so it was not realizing it should be keeping "this header with that paragraph".